# NodeJS - how to call one API, receive an array of results and then trigger multiple API calls and consolidate the results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to learn more about asynchronous Javascript. Kindly help.

What I am trying to achieve - from the json place holder API, retrieve a list of posts; for each item in the posts array, retrieve the user details and then add the user details object to the posts array. I am executing this in a Node Js environment locally.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

let toggleOne = true;

// Async function to retrieve the user details for a given user Id
const fetchUser = async (userId) => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userId}`)
      const json = await response.json();
      return json;
}

const addUserDetails = (posts) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            posts.map(post => {
                  fetchUser(post.userId)
                        .then(userDetails => {
                              // Print once to determine the sequence of operation
                              toggleOne ? console.log('Adding user.') : ''
                              toggleOne = false;

                              // add user details retrieved from fetchUser function to the posts object
                              post.userDetails = userDetails
                              return post
                        })
                        .catch(err => reject(err))
            })
            resolve(posts);
      })
}

// Async function to retrieve all posts
const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      const posts = await response.json();
      return posts
}

fetchPosts()
      .then(posts => addUserDetails(posts))
      .then(postsWithUserDetails => {
            console.log(postsWithUserDetails[0])
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I am expecting the `console.log(postsWithUserDetails[0])` to print below:

```
{
  userId: 1,
  id: 1,
  title: 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit',
  body: 'quia et suscipit\n',
  userDetails: { ... }
}
```

but its printing below which is the output of the first API request.

```
{
  userId: 1,
  id: 1,
  title: 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit',
  body: 'quia et suscipit\n'
}
```

I believe I am making an error and resolving the promise too early but not able to figure out how to get it to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Use `for...loop` instead of `.map`.

Comment: Thank you - that worked as well.

const addUserDetailsForLoop = async (posts) => {
      for (const post of posts) {
            const data = await fetchUser(post.userId);
            post.userDetails = data;
      }
      return posts
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the result of `posts.map()` which is the main issue. You're also resolving all the promises in the array.

Here's my version (untested, but hope it helps)

```js
const addUserDetails = (posts) => {
  return Promise.all( 
    posts.map(async post => {
      const userDetails = await fetchUser(post.userId);
      post.userDetails = userDetails;
      return post;
    })
  })
}
```